# Empty WebMethod generates NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using asp.net aspx engine.

I have a aspx.cs file in which I have an empty WebMethod as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SetIsHandled(int id, bool isHandled)
{

}
```

On my dev environment all works fine. But when I deploy I get the NullReferenceException. I know it gets to the server since I get 500 (Internal Server Rrror).

How can I get this error if my method is empty?

Comment: Post your whole method

Comment: Where do you see the NullReferenceException, is it fault exception at client side ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan "How can I get this error if my method is empty?" The method is empty, nothing to post. Gal, try to debug?

Comment: First convince us it is about this method - do the page and other WebMethods run OK? Then go look for the exception details, stack trace etc.

Comment: The method is exactly how it is posted. I get internal server error when I deploy to prod. On my local the breakpoint hit and the call is successful

Comment: when i investigate the network tab in chrome I can see the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I published the site using precompiled configuration. the contactus.aspx page was not copied to the server and although the page loaded it had a problem with the webmethod